# WordPress Divi Theme page not loading in Chrome and FireFox

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using Divi theme for my website and site is working absolutely fine but my issue is, wp-admin only works Safari browser from MAC machine. If I try to open from any other browser then it just shows me all the details without Divi settings for the page that I have made

Screenshot of console error:

http://prntscr.com/if4fu8

Comment: Please don't add code formatting to random things just to avoid the code requirement filter. I expect readers will want to see your JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the theme and then re-installing it through `FTP`, this will usually fix any problems that you are experiencing.